# Calculating Log-likelihood using Raphson and Jacobian matrices?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, interpolation

I am reading the following paper:

http://www.ntuzov.com/Nik_Site/Niks_files/Research/papers/stat_arb/Ahmed_2009.pdf

and in particular page 13. I want to try and calculate lambda_t(p) = exp^(Beta^T x_t) but I am having problems with the fact beta is derived from a log-likelihood estimation and also jacobian matrices, which require newton raphson:

[image]

Now I never did a degree in maths (I did engineering) but I am *reasonably* mathematical. I need therefore quite a bit of help trying to work out how to actually implement the above in code. I am trying to calculate the order rate, lambda_t(p) = exp^(Beta^T x_t).

I found this, which I think may be answering my question:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method#Example

**If the above link is no good, would someone be able to give me a really basic example of how I could calculate beta, so that I can then calculate lambda_t(p) = exp^(Beta^T x_t)?**

Does anyone know what T is representing?

I wasn't sure if I need to implement newton raphson, as well as the jacobian method, or whether the latter encompasses that.

Help most appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wiki link above is okay, but when using Newton-Raphson and Jacobi with functions and vectors like yours, I would actually read [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) instead. A little more complex, but that's because it's more generally applicable then the link you referenced. Your trying to find a $\beta$ that solves the MLE equation:

For the NR iteration, your iterating from $\beta$-value to $\beta$-value along the function until you reach the solution, which is the desired $\beta$-value. The Jacobian represents the derivative of the function you need to solve, in this case the MLE; it allows you to iterate properly along the curve (derivative = a function's rate of change). On the wiki page, $\beta: MLE(\beta)=0$ analogous to $x: f(x)=0$, and $f'(x)$ is analogous to $J(\beta)$.

> Does anyone know what T is representing?

**T** is simply the transpose operation (note that it says $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^p$)- the vector $\mathbf{x_t}$ looks to me like it should be $\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$, otherwise the next equation (the summation) would not have enough $\mathbf{x_i}$ column vectors.

> I wasn't sure if I need to implement newton raphson, as well as the jacobian method, or **whether the latter encompasses that.**

Other way around: *Newton-Raphson* (your last equation) encompasses the Jacobian (denoted $J$; it's inverse is used).

**Note** The Newton Raphson technique doesn't iterate until the error goes to zero: it takes an infinite amount of time to do so. Instead, set an upper-bound (a given tolerance $\epsilon$) on the error between $\beta$-values (using the 2-norm of the difference), and use that as a while-loop condition for your $\beta_n$ iterations.

The first thing you'll need to do is come up with an "educated guess" of an initial value, call it $\beta_0$. Whenever possible, try to think of typical $\beta$ values for the given scenario, and pick something around there.

From here, you need to calculate the (1) Jacobian matrix and (2) partial derivative for that $\beta$-value, where each element is given by Eq3 and Eq2 (respectively). You can use for-loops to iterate through $jac$ and $mle$ and create the matrix/vector element-by-element (since each element requires a summation). Define functions where the only parameter you have to pass to them is $\beta$, and let them output $J(\beta_n)$ and $\frac{\partial\log L}{\partial\beta}$.

Note the following relationships:

- MLE (Eq 2) is the partial derivative of Eq 1; it's one element of a vector.
- Jacobian (Eq 3) is the partial derivative of Eq 2; it's one element of a matrix.
- The jacobian is size $p\times p$ and $mle$ is a $p$-vector, since the
  $\beta$-vector is $\in\mathbb{R}^p$.

From there, you have all the values you need to get $\beta_1$ (a.k.a. $\beta_{n+1}$) from Eq4. Using this new $\beta$ value, compare the change in beta to the tolerance, and iterate through the equations with the new $\beta$ value if needed.

In terms of code:

1. define $mle(\beta_n)$ and $jac(\beta_n)$ using equations 2 and 3 above
2. Initialize $\Delta\beta=10^8$

**while $err\geq\epsilon$**
{

$\Delta\beta = [jac(\beta_n)]^{-1}*mle(\beta_n)$;

$err = ||\Delta\beta||$;

$\beta_{n+1} = \beta_{n} + \Delta\beta$;

}

Just a quick note: although the iteration above shows the inverse of the jacobian being used, for large matrices this becomes computationally expensive. You didn't specify what language you were using, but if it's something like MATLAB, use $jac(\beta_n)\backslash mle(\beta_n)$, as gaussian elimination saves loads of time.

Comment: Thanks for this- one thing which did puzzle me which I dont think you covered- the very last equation includes "dlog L/dbeta", referring to the log L in the first equation. How do I evaluate this, because it contains beta, which is what I am using all of this to determine in the first place?

Comment: The first equation is written only to show how to derive the second equation, it's not actually used in the NR. [This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) shows that NR is solving some function `f`, where `f(x)=0`; in this case, `f(x)` is the MLE.

Comment: Another small question, as I understand it a jacobian matrix contains n-th derivatives on each row. What is it (in this context) that I will actually be inserting in to each row of my jacobian matrix here? I'm not sure what type of data I should be using for beta? All I have are arrival rates of stock prices, and they are numeric values, not functions?

Comment: Each element will be the numerical result of Eq.3's summation (which changes each iteration because $\beta$ changes), so besides the $y$ you have, you'll also need the $x_t$-matrix. I'm not too familiar with the topic itself, so I'm not sure what that should look like or how to create one for your case. You can technically choose any initial $\beta$-value, it'll just take a bit longer to converge if it's further from the actual solution.

Comment: For an initial beta guess, try something like $(0.5,0.5,...,0.5)$.

Comment: Sorry for asking this, but at which stages will I have to do differentiation? I think I may have been worrying too much and its more a case of plugging in numbers- I was terrified I had to differentiate a lot of the equations from the paper?

Comment: There is no differentiation required, the differentiation was used for deriving the equations themselves. All you'll need to do is "plug-and-chug" because beta is the only thing changing. You could hard code a function that takes in $x_t,y,\beta$ and spits out the numerical matrices/vectors.

Comment: ok- I get what is happening now. I was getting worried because I didn't realise the last part of Eq 4 was just Eq 2 (which is the differential of Eq1). Apologies! Right, my only question remaining is why did they provide me with Eq 3? Eq 1 was provided to create Eq 2 and Eq 2 is used in Eq 4 - but where will I use Eq 3? Thanks for bearing with me

Comment: Eq. 3 is element $J(j,k)$ of the Jacobian matrix (because it's with respect to $\beta_j\beta_k$). It's the partial derivative of Eq. 2 with respect to $\beta_j$.

Comment: That doesn't appear in Eq. 4- so why did they provide it? I did read your answer but wasn't too sure where you were implying it would be used. So far I understand the situation as follows: I need to implement Eq 4. and Eqs. 1 and 2 are part of Eq 4.- hence i'm a little stumped where I will be using Eq. 3. Thanks

Comment: $J(j,k)$ is element $(j,k)$ of $J(\beta_n)$, which is the matrix inverted in Eq. 4. You use Eq. 3 to populate the jacobian matrix, and invert the matrix to use in Eq 4. I'll clarify in the answer a bit.

Comment: Thanks!!!- and in Eq 4 is the last part just notation, or is it saying each element of the inverse Jacobian is being multiplied by the partial differential?